# Finite State Automaton Transition Diagram

Tags: finite-automata, finite-model-theory

I got an alphabet E={x,y,z}. And i want to create a finite state automaton that accepts strings consisting of at least two x's, followed by at most three y's followed by any number of z's. And i want to draw a transition diagram for this.

And i am new to this concept, So far i got here. And i know i am wrong so if someone can help me out would be great. Thanks[image]

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 0):

> at most three y's  means that you can either have none 'y', or 1 'y' , or 2 'y'  so you should also accept such strings